# After fully blocking public access to s3, Even admin users is not able to access it

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have been instructed to block public access to s3. so I blocked it as below:

[image]

Now I tried to give myself access to see or download the PDFs in the bucket. So I created a Full Access policy as below:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListStorageLensConfigurations",
                "s3:GetAccessPoint",
                "s3:PutAccountPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:GetAccountPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:ListAccessPoints",
                "s3:ListJobs",
                "s3:PutStorageLensConfiguration",
                "s3:CreateJob"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        }
    ]
}
```

and attached to my IAM user. Even after this, I still get an access denied message when I click on the object URL available at the object level:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`Solution` : Instead of opening the HTTPS link to the object, use the Amazon S3 console to download the object. When you download the object, the request includes the credentials that you used to sign in to the Amazon S3 console.

`Explanation` : [Why am I getting an Access Denied error when I open the link to an Amazon S3 object that I have access to?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-access-denied-error/)

Another option is to use aws cli [s3 cp](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3/index.html) command to download the object.

Answer (score 0):

Within the Amazon S3 management console, there are two ways to access an object.

The **Object URL** link simply opens a browser tab with the indicated URL (eg `punchs3qa.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/100000.pdf`). This is an "anonymous URL" since it does not identify the user. Objects in Amazon S3 are private by default, which is why the object is not accessible. (This is good!)

To access the object using your IAM User, you can use the **Open** command in the **Object actions** menu. This will generate a **signed URL**, which includes authentication information. It will look something like:

```
https://punchs3qa.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/100000.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=xxx&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAxxx&X-Amz-Signature=xxx
```

Amazon S3 will then verify the signature and will permit the object to be opened.

Similarly, you could access the object using the AWS CLI, using your IAM User credentials:

```
aws s3 cp s3://punchs3qa/100000.pdf .
```

That command will copy the file to the local directory.

**Bottom line:** It is doing exactly what you want. You just need to identify yourself when accessing the object.